# How to have android { } block outside build.gradle.kts

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I used to have the following structure before migrating to .kts:

`app/build.gradle`

```
...
apply from "secrets.gradle"

android {

...

}
```

`secrets.gradle`

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
       ...
       // extra stuff that used to get merged
    }
}
```

I recently converted them to .kts. I get `Unresolved reference: android` in secrets.gradle.kts.

Commenting out `apply(from = "secrets.gradle.kts")` from app/build.gradle.kts gets rid of the error, so it seems like android { } block is not allowed in secrets.gradle.kts

Is there a way to have android { } block in secrets.gradle.kts and get the previous merging behaviour?